# Ruby webserver - callback when the request has been served

Tags: ruby, callback, webserver

Is there any way to know when a request has been served by a ruby webserver (webrick, evma_httpserver, whatever?)

Goal is to serve 2 static files and shutdown server after the second file has been served to the client.
It seems i can not find anything related to this, so any pointers are welcome..

Comment: I may be wrong but I don't think there's any verification sent to the server, when the client receives a message. The server only knows when it's finished _sending_ the message.

Comment: I'm not sure but since it is a tcp connection, i imagine that tcp makes sure the packets have been delivered before the response is considered 'sent'. Would be interested if this is actually true..    


I have tried the solution from Зелёный and it works for me. In my case it is not that critical because server and client are in the same local subnet and lost packets should be rare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just shutdown server then the second file is served. Here is an **example**:

server.rb

```
require 'webrick'

server = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new :Port => 8000, :DocumentRoot => '/'
server.mount_proc '/' do |req, res|
  # response with simple html body
  res.body = '
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>My Webpage</title>
      <!-- first file -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/one_file.css" type="text/css">
      <!-- second file -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/second_file.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>Hello world!</h1>
    </body>
  </html>'
end
server.mount_proc '/one_file.css' do |req, res|
  res.body = 'h1 { color: blue; }'
end
server.mount_proc '/second_file.css' do |req, res|
  res.body = 'h1 { color: red; }'
  puts "Shutdown server !"
  server.shutdown
end
server.start
```

Run server.rb:

```
$~  ruby server.rb 
[2018-09-26 11:02:21] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2018-09-26 11:02:21] INFO  ruby 2.4.1 (2017-03-22) [x86_64-linux]
[2018-09-26 11:02:21] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=24224 port=8000
::1 - - [26/Sep/2018:11:02:24 MSK] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 262
- -> /
::1 - - [26/Sep/2018:11:02:24 MSK] "GET /one_file.css HTTP/1.1" 200 19
http://localhost:8000/ -> /one_file.css
::1 - - [26/Sep/2018:11:02:24 MSK] "GET /second_file.css HTTP/1.1" 200 18
http://localhost:8000/ -> /second_file.css
::1 - - [26/Sep/2018:11:02:24 MSK] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 262
http://localhost:8000/ -> /favicon.ico
[2018-09-26 11:02:25] INFO  going to shutdown ...
[2018-09-26 11:02:25] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
$~
```

Both files are served:

[image]

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for! Thanks a lot for the clear and working example!! 
I was under the impression that the response will not be served when server.shutdown is called during the response block, but failed to validate that belief. I have now tried it and even with slightly bigger responses the response is served successfully before the server shuts down. Thanks again for helping me out : )